# php some vars in session lost in the same page

Tags: php, session

The session data lost in the same page.The code like this:

`var_dump($_SESSION); //  $_SESSION['uid'] has value of "2", and there are many other values;
$uid = $_SESSION['uid']; //$_SESSION['uid'] will be missing at this line!
var_dump($_SESSION); //  $_SESSION will lost some values, but not all values;`

The value changes just in two line and I haven't change it at all;

I though this may be a bug of php. Is that true?
Is any one who meet this problem before?

My php version is 5.5.6.

Comment: Can you give the code that exists between those lines, please?

Comment: have you start session_start() before your code ??

Comment: there is no other code in these line @MarkOrmesher;

Comment: I am sure i have type session_start(); @TalhaQ